# How to get full content on newapi.org

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, express

I am creating a website by using the api of newsorg. I get this as output when I send the request to api:

```
"articles": [
-{
-"source": {
"id": null,
"name": "Hindustan Times"
},
"author": "HT Correspondent | Edited by Ashutosh Tripathi",
"title": "‘Come back to your home in Jaipur’: Congress to Sachin Pilot after his ‘not joining BJP’ remark - Hindustan Times",
"description": "It was only yesterday that the party sacked Pilot as deputy chief minister and also from the post of Rajasthan Pradesh Congress chief.",
"url": "https://www.hindustantimes.com/india-news/come-back-to-your-home-in-jaipur-congress-to-sachin-pilot-after-his-not-joining-bjp-remark/story-XafsBaEGxr8MqS5rqlsFsI.html",
"urlToImage": "https://www.hindustantimes.com/rf/image_size_960x540/HT/p2/2020/07/15/Pictures/_c339ab02-c68e-11ea-be81-f7b2e356804f.jpg",
"publishedAt": "2020-07-15T11:32:00Z",
"content": "Stop all conversation with the BJP and head back to your home in Jaipur, the Congress impressed upon Sachin Pilot in yet another outreach attempt. The state has been teetering on the edge since Pilot… [+2049 chars]"
},
```

(This is just a part of the result).
I want to get access to the complete content.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation says :

> **content**
> *string*
> The unformatted content of the article, where available. This is truncated to 200 chars.

You cant have all the content, only 200 chars, you should go to the URL to have the full content

They dont let's you "steal" all the website content